# Tensorflow Serving Test Failing

Tags: tensorflow-serving

I am trying to build Tensorflow Serving on Ubuntu. I have compiled Tensorflow and Tensorflow serving from source without error, but when I run:

```
bazel test -c opt tensorflow_serving/...
```

I get the following error:

```
//tensorflow_serving/model_servers:tensorflow_model_server_test         
TIMEOUT in 315.1s
```

All of the other tests pass.

When I look in the log file, I only see the following:

```
exec ${PAGER:-/usr/bin/less} "$0" || exit 1
```

I don't know what the error is, or why the model server test is failing.

Answer (score 0):

It could simply be that the test is running slow in your environment and would pass if configured with a more generous timeout. Try editing the BUILD file to set the test size to [enormous](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/common-definitions.html#test.size) and see if it passes then.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue in TensorFlow Serving. Please refer to [this Github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/589) for more information.